# From or by. Which one to use here?

Tags: grammar

Someone asked me 
What is that stain on your shirt?

I replied
It's sand
I might have got it from lying on the beach/by lying on the beach

Which one is correct?

I mean to say that
I might have got it when I was laying on the beach

Which preposition to be used here
By or from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *from*. *By* suggests that you deliberately lay on the beach ***in order to*** stain your shirt, which seems unlikely!